# QUnit asyncTest does not continue after error

Tags: javascript, testing, qunit

How can I tell QUnit to consider errors during `asyncTest` as test failures and continue to next test?

here is an example which QUnit stops running after a `ReferenceError`: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bakhshi/7VfSb/)

Comment: I can use `testTimeouts` but it risky as test may take much time and it will take so much time to run all test if you have some tests with errors in them!

Answer (score 1):

Errors in asynchronous tests die silently if they arise while QUnit isn't officially running.

The simplest solution is to wrap every `asyncTest` contents in a try/catch block that propagates any errors *after* restarting QUnit. We don't actually have to pollute the code with a million try/catches--we can decorate your existing methods automagically.

For example:

```
// surrounds any function with a try/catch block to propagate errors to QUnit when
// called during an asyncTest
function asyncTrier(method) {
    return function () {
        try{
            // if the method runs normally, great!
            method();
        } catch (e) {
            // if not, restart QUnit and pass the error on
            QUnit.start();
            throw new (e);
        }
    };
}

QUnit.asyncTest("sample", 1, function () {
        setTimeout(asyncTrier(function(){
           var foo = window.nonexistentobj.toString() + ""; // throws error

           QUnit.ok("foo defined", !!foo)
           QUnit.start();
       }), 1000);
});
```

Forked your Fiddle, with a sample wrapping method to automatically apply such a try/catch around every asynchronous block: http://jsfiddle.net/bnMWd/4/

(**Edit**: updated per comments.)

Comment: thanks, but there is still a problem, `QUnit` will think that my test has finished after calling `start`. this will result in misplaced outputs and if you run an automated test (e.g. karma) they will not know that you still have tests to run and will end your test session after your last `start`. here is an update to your code : http://jsfiddle.net/bakhshi/bnMWd/2/

Comment: Aha! New solution -- a bit more elaborate (requires wrapping of each timeout block) but propagates errors and is still readable.