# In QUnit, how to evaluate thrown errors in asyncTest()?

Tags: javascript, qunit

For example,

```
asyncTest('test1', function() {
    var callback = function() {
        throw new TypeError('foobar'); // <-- i want to evaluate this error is being thrown
    }
    throws(
        function() {
            anAsyncFunction(callback);
        }
    );
});
```

The question is, where to put the throws(), where to put the start()?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [QUnit asyncTest does not continue after error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19238530/qunit-asynctest-does-not-continue-after-error)